# trying to make a program that would let me complete recaptcha manually on python

Tags: python, selenium, web, bots, recaptcha

So I just started to use python and I have a problem when accessing a website. So for the start I'm working on a bot as my a small project and when I try to access this page, a recaptcha shows up. I tried to resolve it manually but after I complete it it refreshes the page I need to do it again.
Can anyone help me out?
My code rn:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://raffle.shinzo.paris/en/air-jordan-1-retro-hi-og-a-ma-maniere/")
```

Comment: Let me guess, recaptcha shows up 100% of the time when you webscrape but only some of the time when you open that link manually?

Comment: @LukeHamilton it shows up every time even when I'm browsing normally but the thing is that when I complete it in the generated chrome page it refreshes my recaptcha instead of redirecting me to the other page.

Comment: It appears that the website is using some kind of sophisticated bot protection mechanism, which results in getting stuck in an endless loop of solving the CAPTCHA when using selenium..

Comment: @KamaleshS is there any way I can pass that?